# What kind of surface is described (explicitly) by the product of bivariate quadratic and bivariate linear?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, conic-sections, cubics

A bivariate linear function has 3 coefficients (degrees of freedom) and (explicitly) describes a plane:

$z=f_1(x,y)=a_1+a_2x+a_3y$

A bivariate quadratic function has 6 coefficients (degrees of freedom) and (explicitly) describes a paraboloid.

$z=f_2(x,y)=b_1+b_2x+b_3y+b_4xy+b_5x^2+b_6y^2$

A bivariate cubic function has 10 coefficients (degrees of freedom).

$z=f_3(x,y)=c_1+c_2x+c_3y+c_4xy+c_5x^2+c_6y^2+c_7x^2y+c_8xy^2+c_9x^3+c_{10}y^3$

I presume the product $f_{2.5}(x,y)=f_1(x,y)f_2(x,y)$ has 3+6-1=8 degrees of freedom ("-1" arising from the fact that scaling $f_1$ and scaling $f_2$ have the same effect on $f_{2.5}$).

In summary:

```
                     DoF             Shape
linear                3     z=f_1    plane
quadratic             6     z=f_2    paraboloid
linear x quadratic    8     z=f_2.5  ?
cubic                10     z=f_3
```

Question: Is there anything interesting we can say about the geometric nature of $f_{2.5}$? We have intuition on what a plane ($f_1$) looks like, and what paraboloids (${f_2}$) look like. What can we say (even in vague language) about what $f_{2.5}$ looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Given $$\begin{aligned}
f_1(x,y) &= a_1 + a_2 x + a_3 y \\
f_2(x,y) &= b_1 + b_2 x + b_3 y + b_4 x y + b_5 x^2 + b_6 y^2 \\
f_3(x,y) &= c_1 + c_2 x + c_3 y + c_4 x y + c_5 x^2 + c_6 y^2 + c_7 x^2 y + c_8 x y^2 + c_9 x^3 + c_{10} y^3 \\
\end{aligned}$$
then
$$f_1(x, y) f_2(x, y) = f_3(x, y)$$
where $$\begin{aligned}
c_1 &= a_1 b_1 \\
c_2 &= a_1 b_2 + a_2 b_1 \\
c_3 &= a_1 b_3 + a_3 b_1 \\
c_4 &= a_1 b_4 + a_2 b_3 + a_3 b_2 \\
c_5 &= a_1 b_5 + a_2 b_2 \\
c_6 &= a_1 b_6 + a_3 b_3 \\
c_7 &= a_3 b_5 + a_2 b_4 \\
c_8 &= a_2 b_6 + a_3 b_4 \\
c_9 &= a_2 b_5 \\
c_{10} &= a_3 b_6 \\
\end{aligned}$$

When you multiply a polynomial of degree $N$ with a polynomial of degree $M$, you get a polynomial of degree $N+M$.  This applies even to multivariate polynomials.

Comment: Sure, the product can be expressed as a cubic but it is more constrained than a cubic that has free coefficients. It has two fewer degrees of freedom.

Comment: @Museful: Then the question seems to me to be whether irreducible bivariate cubic polynomials of form $z = f_3(x, y)$ have any interesting properties compared to reducible bivariate cubic polynomials $z = f_1(x, y)f_2(x,y)$.  Personally, I do not believe so (to me they just look like smooth bumps), but hopefully someone else can enlighten us.